# Facebook connect approbation

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-login

**Context:** For a Hackathon I building an app (web based - Ruby on Rails) that matches people based on their commun interests. For that I want to use Facebook connect and instantaneously get a person's likes so I can match him/her with someone with similar interests.

**The problem:** But apparently I can't access someone's likes through Facebook connect unless my app has been approved by Facebook. But without this login there is no app (and I can't wait 3-7 business days to have a working app).

Is there a way I can get my app to work (even if it's only with a set of approved users/testers)? Or do I have to come up with a an alternative page where my users will have to manually enter their interests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no shortcut for the Login Review. What you can do is adding specific users (via your app's dashboard) you want to test your functionality with as admins/developers/testers of the specific app.

This will allow them to be able to grant your app extended permissions as `user_likes` without Login Review.

Also, I think Facebook already provides an endpoint for your use case:

```
/{user-id}?fields=context{mutual_likes}
```

which will produce something like

```
{
  "context": {
    "mutual_likes": {
      "data": [
        {
          "category": "Media/news/publishing", 
          "name": "Mashable", 
          "id": "18807449704"
        }, 
        {
          "category": "Food/beverages", 
          "name": "Coca-Cola", 
          "id": "40796308305"
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "before": "MTg4MDc0NDk3MDQ=", 
          "after": "NDA3OTYzMDgzMDU="
        }
      }, 
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 2
      }
    }
  }, 
  "id": "123456789"
}
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user.context/mutual_likes
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page.context/friends_who_like
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit#testpermissions
- https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your_app_id}/roles/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to create temporary test users

Comment: You could, but I'd better go with real users for your case (common interests)